# Is there any way to increase charisma in The Dark Spire?

Tags: the-dark-spire

I wanted to make my warrior character a Paladin, but apparently it requires a high charisma attribute.

The other attributes can be increased by training; is there a way to increase the charisma attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, since I didn't get a response I checked a FAQ (I didn't really want to do so, because of the spoilers). If you plan on your warrior becoming a Paladin, make sure he has at least 10 points allocated in Charisma when starting.

I created a new char and leveled him up with the rest of the party...